# Variation Inflation Factor Gives inf

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor, statsmodels

I have a dataset that contains 292 attributes. I want to calculate VIF to address multicollinearity in dataset. Here is a snippet which I have used to calculate VIF

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor  
def calculate_vif_(X):
    variables = list(X.columns)
    vif = {variable:variance_inflation_factor(exog=X.values, exog_idx=ix) for ix,variable in enumerate(list(X.columns))}
    return vif

calculate_vif_(train)
```

Here is the example of output

```
    {'0_13_all': inf,
     '0_13_female': inf,
     '0_13_male': inf,
     '0_17_all': inf,
     '0_17_female': inf,
     '0_17_male': inf,
     '0_6_all': inf,
     '0_6_female': inf,
     '0_6_male': inf,
     'ID_big_road1': 4.3585189697040807,
 'ID_big_road2': 3.3490088398280924,
 'ID_bus_terminal': 8.4094163765196654,
 'ID_metro': 4.3989179012404227,
 'ID_railroad_station_avto': 6.1953273896236496,
 'ID_railroad_station_walk': 6.765644767428685,

}
```

The dataset contains only numeric variables and I have removed all the NA's. 
I couldnt figure out why some of the variables have `inf` as output.
Is there any other cleaner way to address multicollinearity?

Comment: De-bugging your code is off topic here but there does seem to be a possible statistics question here. Is all=female+male?

Comment: You can't include both female and male.  And, of course, those are not continuous variables.

Comment: These VIFs tell you there is perfect collinearity: you have completely redundant variables.  The very first thing you should do to address collinearity is to *think about what the variables mean.* Unless you are coding for more than two genders, for instance, including an indicator of maleness is completely redundant with an indicator of femaleness.

Comment: None of the variables are cateogorical  in nature. they are of numerical type...Does that mean I have high collinearity between variable?

Comment: Even I'm addressing a similar issue with the classic Melbourne house prediction problem, I have one hot encoded few nominal features and their VIF is inf. My question is since there will be a good correlation between one-hot-encoded columns of the same categorical feature (for instance if Gender is one hot encoded as Gen_Male and Gen_Female columns, they will have a very high correlation). Should I let them stay in the regression model or remove them because their vif = inf??
Thanks in Advance :D 0 9.941227 Rooms 1 1.124820 Date 2 2.128941 Distance 3 9.451651 Bedroom2 . . . .
18 inf R_name_Eas